# Running a SCNNode animation just once on Scene Kit

Tags: objective-c, animation, 3d, scenekit, scnnode

I'm trying to run an animation from a .dae file (3D model file) just once, this is my code:

```
SCNNode *object = (SCNNode*)[self getMyPlayerObject];
NSString *key = @"hit";
CAAnimation *animation = [_animations[key] copy];
[animation setSpeed:1];
[animation setTimeOffset:0];
[object addAnimation:animation forKey:key];
```

I've tried using `animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;` but is not working, I've tried setting a delegate and tried to detect it with the `animationDidStop:finished:` method, but it doesn't even get called, there's something weird when using `CAAnimations` on `SCNNodes`from DAE animations.

Is there any way of doing it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the animation repeating? Check `repeatCount` and `repeatDuration`.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist I set repeatCount to 1 and it did it just once! Thank you. Can you set it as an answer? Or should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your animation is likely configured to be repeating. Check the `repeatCount` property to see if it's larger than `1`. Setting it to 1 will repeat the animation once, but you can also set it to 0 to ignore it. if that's not it, you can look at the `repeatDuration` property and set it to 0 (to ignore it) if it's not already 0.